# How to run chrome driver in background using selenium with Ruby for Mac OSx?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless, selenium-ruby

Sometimes, the browser window comes to the foreground and I'm clicking it accidentally which makes the test fails on some occasions. So, I just want to know, is there any way that I can keep the chrome driver window in the background.

Details:
< ChromeDriver version: 2.28.455517 >
< Chrome version: 58.0.3029.96 >

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

A few words about the solution to your Question:

1. As per best practices, you should try to execute your Test-scripts / Automation-framework in an isolated *Test Environment* with all the required *Hardware* and *Software* configurations and setup.
2. While the execution is in process, there should be no manual user interaction in-between.
3. In-case you want to do multitasking, use Ghost/Headless Browsers. You will find a detailed discussion in [Which drivers support “no-browser”/“headless” testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368002/which-drivers-support-no-browser-headless-testing/48368054#48368054).
4. [Htmlunitdriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver) & [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.8.html) are the two mostly widely used Ghost/Headless Browsers.
5. If you are specific about using ChromeDriver you can use Chrome headless as per the [documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md) [here](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/5336747).

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost rule is that we should not do any other work while your scripts are running. We may use actions class for hovering., etc, while you move your cursor it may lead to failing your test case. Hope It will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using headless switch available for Chrome.

This will run the automation in the headless mode and you will not be disturbed.

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--headless')
```

Afterward, initiate Chrome.