# MicrosoftWebDriver 16299, 15063 doesn't work when I minimise Edge browser window

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge, microsoft-webdriver

When I execute tests using MicrosoftWebDriver for Edge all works fine, but when I minimise the window all tests become failed. Does Edge or MicrosoftWebDriver have any options to avoid that behavior?

Comment: Why do you want to _minimize the window_?

Comment: It looks like Edge needs some kind of visualisation. If my PC goes to sleep mode tests fail too. Even if nobody open a VM with selenium-grid server test can't start.

Answer (score 0):

As you have been trying to **minimise** the *Browser Window* while your *Test Execution* is *In Progress* it will be against all the *Best Practices*. At this point it is worth to mention that as ***Selenium* mocks the *User Actions*** hence *Selenium* needs *Browser* **focus**. If the *focus* is lost *Selenium* won't be able to execute the lines of code. Consider the following steps while your *Test Execution* :

- **Browser Maximize** : While you execute your tests always keep the *Web Browser* maximized so majority of the elements are within the [**Viewport**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)
- As per best practices, you should try to execute your *Test Scripts* / *Automation Framework* in an isolated *Test Environment* away from **Manual Intervention** with all the required *Software* and *Hardware* configurations and setup.

  You can find a detailed discussion in [How to run chrome driver in background using selenium with Ruby for Mac OSx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863837/how-to-run-chrome-driver-in-background-using-selenium-with-ruby-for-mac-osx/43865825#43865825)
- You also have an option to use *Google Chrome* or *Mozilla Firefox* in **Headless** version.

  For *Firefox* you can find a detailed discussion in [How to make firefox headless programatically in Selenium with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programatically-in-selenium-with-python/46768243#46768243)

  For *Chrome* you can find a detailed discussion in [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH error with Headless Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085270/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executabl/46089751#46089751)

  For *Ghost Browser* you can find a detailed discussion in [Which drivers support “no-browser”/“headless” testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368002/which-drivers-support-no-browser-headless-testing/48368054#48368054)

Comment: I have Asure VM for test execution but in my case tests run only if that VM is opened by Remote Desctop Connection. If I try to execute tests without RDP it doesn't work.

Comment: Even if my working PC goes to the sleeping mod tests fail.