# How to force chrome to launch in the background?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, ubuntu

When I run GUI tests (Selenium, Java. Launched from IntelliJ idea on Ubuntu 16.04).

Each new test opens a new chrome browser (and close it when the test finishes) in the foreground, stilling the focus from what ever I am doing. 
I can't run headless or change the tests to only launch a single browser and do clean up from test to test.

Any way to tell chrome to launch in the background? any relevant flag? If not maybe some way to tell Ubuntu to move Chrome to the background?

Solutions are welcomed, thanks!

Comment: Check this discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49896324/microsoftwebdriver-16299-15063-doesnt-work-when-i-minimise-edge-browser-window/49901936#49901936

Comment: I've checked it, not really helping but thanks anyway :)